# Download a f3 file through the Autodesk Data management api

Tags: autodesk-data-management

I have the following python function to try and prepare a download for a fusion created project. Getting the downloadFormats for this file will yield [{'fileType': 'f3z'}] as the available formats for it.
But using the following function

```
def create_download(access_token, project_id, version_id, format_type):
    url = f"https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/{project_id}/downloads"
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
        "Content-Type": "application/vnd.api+json",
    }
    data = {
        "jsonapi": {"version": "1.0"},
        "data": {
            "type": "downloads",
            "attributes": {
                "format": {
                    "fileType": format_type,
                },
            },
            "relationships": {
                "source": {
                    "data": {
                        "type": "versions",
                        "id": version_id,
                    }
                }
            },
        },
    }

    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)
    response.raise_for_status()
    res = response.json()
    return res
```

Will give the following body back:
{'jsonapi': {'version': '1.0'}, 'errors': [{'id': '6c5e1628-3c96-45e3-9af5-6b316f87f823', 'status': '400', 'detail': 'BadRequest'}]}

I have checked that the project id, version id and access token are all valid.

Using any other value for fileType will return the following body:
{'jsonapi': {'version': '1.0'}, 'errors': [{'id': 'b1af1d88-d8b6-4e85-a48d-e6febd52b3a4', 'status': '400', 'code': 'BAD_INPUT', 'title': 'One or more input values in the request were bad', 'detail': "Download fileType 'f3' is not supported."}]}

The file is created through fusion and is a template file to be used in other projects, which is why I would like to automatically copy this file to different folders. I found downloading the file and uploading would probably be the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The message "Download fileType 'f3' is not supported." suggests that somehow the message you send to the endpoint ends up saying "**f3**" instead of "**f3z**"

You can double-check that by sending the message to a utility website like https://webhook.site/ and check there the exact message your program sends out.

Also, there is a sample desktop app that is using the same endpoint and it still seems to work fine for me:

[image]

Give that a try: https://github.com/adamenagy/a360backup-data.management-csharp

However, please note that **f3z** is an **archive** format, uploading it back to **Fusion Team** will just be considered a **zip** - I don't think you can do anything with it directly, but you can use **Fusion 360** to unwrap it an upload the **f3d** files it contains and set up the references between them.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Any way else I could download the file as 'f3' such that I can upload it to another folder and immediately use it in fusion? Ideally I wanted a way to copy a fusion file from one folder to he other, like on the website, but I couldn't get that to work.

Comment: This is the closest I got to that: https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/transfer-files-between-hubs-projects-folders